# conectar AD via php e ssl

Tags: php

Estou a tentar conectar minha aplicação php para autenticação com Active Directory
do Windows Server 2003, usando autenticação segurar ssl. mas ele n conecta retorna esse erro

> PHP Warning:  ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Can't contact
>   LDAP server in /var/www/html/Ldap/teste1.php

//Aqui esta o codigo que uso

```
AD_server = "ldaps://meuservidor";
$AD_Auth_User = "password";

$protocolVersion = 3;
$ldap = ldap_connect($AD_server);
ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, $protocolVersion) ;

ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
ldap_bind($ldap);
if (ldap_errno($ldap)) {
   exit('Nao foi possivel conectar no servidor');
}else{ 
   return true;
}
?>
```

Comment: O erro parece claro que seu script não está conseguindo  se conectar ao servidor. Você está adicionando o *domain controller* e o domínio ao nome dele? Por exemplo: `ldaps://meuservidor.DOMAINCONTROLLER.suaempresa.com.br` dependendo de como está configurado o servidor de AD aí.

Comment: olha com o ldap:meuservidor ele conecta, mas quando uso o ldaps://meuservidor ele n conecta

Comment: Seu servidor do AD está habilitado sobre SSL? O certificado está válido? Da uma olhada nesse [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321051/pt-br).

Comment: ja fiz tudo isso mas não sei o q se passa, ele não quer connectar, ja estou nesse problema faz 7 dias, preciso de ajuda!!

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro realize um teste de conexão na porta 636 do servidor LDAP.

LDAP utiliza a porta 389, já LDAPS (LDAP sobre SSL) utiliza a porta 636. Você consegue conectar nesta porta através de uma conexão telnet?

Comment: sim, usando uma maquina windows, mas quando uso meu pc com ubuntu o servidor fecha logo a conexão

Comment: Você pode tentar realizar um teste de acesso SSL usando o comando: `openssl s_client -connect meuservidor:636`, qual mensagem retorna?

Comment: oi @denisvm estou com dificuldades para alterar senhas através do php ldap você pode me ajudar por favor?

Consigo alterar os dados de email mas quando tento alterar a senha mostra essa mensagem:

Warning: ldap_modify(): Modify: Server is unwilling to perform

Comment: @ThiagoPhilipp, o processo de troca de senha através de LDAP é diferente no caso do Windows. A senha deverá ser alterada através do campo `unicodePwd` utilizando caracteres no formato BER. Segue artigo da Microsoft com maiores informações: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/269190/how-to-change-a-windows-active-directory-and-lds-user-password-through-ldap

Comment: @denisvm Você pode me dar umas dicas de como posso configurar o servidor windows(servidor da rede) e o servidor xampp(máquina local) para conectar via SSL com o código php ldap no AD do Windows e poder ter permissão de alterar a senha dos usuários do AD por favor?